# Get correct width of detail view in UISplitviewController when orientation changes

Tags: c#, ios, orientation, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

The background of my goal is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747000/approaches-for-implementing-a-tripartite-view-for-ipad).

I use a split view controller with a *MasterViewController* and a *DetailViewController*. On the detail view I want to have two table view controllers. The table views are displayed but if orientation changes the width and the positon of the `UITableViewControllers` are wrong.

In my *DetailViewController* I have the following code in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
base.ViewDidLoad ();

float halfSize = View.Bounds.Size.Width / 2;
RectangleF leftArea = new RectangleF (0, 0, halfSize, View.Frame.Size.Height);
RectangleF rightArea = new RectangleF (halfSize, 0, halfSize, View.Frame.Size.Height);

if(documentListController == null)
    documentListController = new DocumentListController ();
if(documentInfoController == null)
    documentInfoController = new DocumentInfoController ();

documentListController.View.Frame = leftArea;
documentListController.View = documentListController.TableView;
documentInfoController.View.Frame = rightArea;
documentInfoController.View = documentInfoController.TableView;
View.AddSubview (documentListController.View);
View.AddSubview (documentInfoController.View);
```

In portrait orientation the width are ok but in landscape the tables are too small (because it has the size when it was in portrait mode).

I tried to use `documentListController.View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;` but it has no effect. I also implemented a notification where I want to detect the orientation change. If I do that in landscape mode the detail view has a width of 703 and in portrait I have a width of 768 (only on first start, values changes if I do some rotation).

How do I get the correct width of the *DetailViewController* regardless of the current orientation?

PS: The code is in `C#` but I'll be also happy if you could provide code in `Objective-C`.

**Edit:**

I'm using the OrientationDidChangeNotification notification to  get the orientation change. Now I noticed if I query `this.View.Bounds.Size.Width` then the values are old values from the orientation before! How do I get the current values?

**Edit 2:**

Now I used hard coded values. I saw that if I switch to landscape and then back to portrait the table views have the same small size. The views needs to be updated. But how?

**Edit 3:**

I also tried to use constraints to set the width correctly:

```
documentListController.View.AddConstraints (
    new []{
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create (documentListController.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, .5f, 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create (documentListController.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, 1, 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create (documentListController.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create (documentListController.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0)
    }
);
documentListController.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

But here I get

> Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?